# can I select columns based on their name in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, select

is there a way to select columns using '%' or 'like'?

for example:

I have a table with 20 columns , and 4 of them are starting with "GPS_"(GPS_long,GPS_Lat,GPS_sat,GPS_Speed)

I want to run something like this:( I know this is NOT the way...)

```
SELECT like '%GPS_%' FROM sample.table
```

so it will bring only the GPS columns  ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Noway in a query, only dynamic SQL in stored procedure may solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, nor should you even consider it.
This is a variation on ...

> Never use "select *" in Production Code

.. and the risk is the same.

At the moment, your table is nice and tidy, with a few columns of limited size.
At some point, someone is going have the "Great Idea" of adding a whole bunch of BLOB fields and populating them with *terabytes* of video data.  If you're unlucky and those new fields just happen to be prefixed "GPS_", then your code would start *retrieving* these fields, even though it has *absolutely no interest* in them.

Always specify the fields that you want to retrieve explicitly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have learn something :-)  . I thought it something handy that can be used

Answer (score 0):

(Not able to add a comment, so write there)

Maybe say something more about your case - is this only to spare some typing or it may happen that these columns will be changed dynamically by something external? Like [@Phil W. said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/284078/213360) you should avoid such solutions, but sometimes it may happen that this is inevitable. Then you may need to have construct such columns list dynamically in some external tool.

Comment: the columns names are static , just to save time in typing. not for production , just for me for testing \ searching specific data .